# avr pd3 and pb3 work together as pwm

Tags: avr

I'm trying the learn timers and pwm methods. I use the timer2 for fast pwm but i just want to use only pd3 for pwm. The code below works two pins together as pwm. How can i split these pins.

mcu is Atmega328p

```
#define F_CPU 16000000UL
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

volatile unsigned char duty_cyc_a,duty_cyc_b;

int main(void)
{

    DDRB = 0b00001000;
    DDRD = 0b00001000;
    PORTD = 0x00;
    PORTB = 0x00;

    TCCR2A = 0b10100011; 
    TCCR2B = 0b00000001; 
    TCNT2 = 0;           
    OCR2A = 117;          
    OCR2B = 117;
    duty_cyc_a=0;   
    duty_cyc_b=255; 

    while (1) 
    {
        PORTB = (1<<3);
        _delay_ms(1000);
        PORTB &= 0;
        _delay_ms(1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at the [manual](http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-8271-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48A-48PA-88A-88PA-168A-168PA-328-328P_datasheet_Complete.pdf), specifically the pages at the end of the section on timer2 to see how setting the registers controls the waveform and pins. The pins are called OC2A and OC2B, which are also names for PB3 and PD3.

Another tip for readable code is to use the macros that describe the pin functions, rather than combine them into one difficult binary number. If the previous writer had done that, your job would be easier.

```
TCCR2A = 0b10100011; 
TCCR2B = 0b00000001;
```

should be

```
TCCR2A = 1 << COM2A1 | 1 << COM2B1 | 1 << WGM21 | 1 << WGM20; 
TCCR2B = 1 << CS20;
```

Now you can see which bits the previous author set to 1. (The rest are set to 0).

Go through the tables in the register section to decide which pins you need to set in these two control registers instead. (You won't use COM2A1, and you will need to choose different WGMx pins.)

Comment: i have made mistakes like this at last few days often. Thank you for your answer